# Mac equivalent to iOS Colour Filters (Tritanopia)

Tags: ios, mac, display, color, accessibility

I have Tritanopia (Blue / Yellow) colour blindness.

In iOS I can use Settings > General > Accessibility > Display Accommodations > Colour Filters > Blue / Yellow Filter to boost the relevant colours on the display.

I looked around but apart from applications hacks and messing with monitor calibrations I couldn't find anything easy.

Is there an equivalent on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the xSCope app to do this using their loupe tool (so it's not for full screen use) for several years and it's a workhorse of other design and measurement goodness. You might check out f.lux as well but that seems to be more bio-perception for decreasing blue hues on a circadian cycle that tracks sunrise and sunset.

- http://xscopeapp.com
- https://justgetflux.com

I don't think this full screen feature is embedded in macOS High Sierra (yet) and it's not explicitly enabled on older Mac OS versions in as usable a format as iOS 11 does. Perhaps later in the year or next year this would come natively.

In the mean time, you could use a third party app or try setting a custom color calibration / display profile for some light correction. I don't think either of the above is as powerful as iOS accessibility, though.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @bmike. Just to clarify, I can use xScope to change boost blue / yellow across the entire Mac display, just like on the iPhone display. Thank you.

Comment: @gentlemanhog I've edited to clarify that xScope only changes the loupe - not the whole screen. You'd need something like f.lux I suppose there.

Comment: Thanks @bmike. Understood. I contacted The IconFactory and they said the same. Thank you for your help anyway. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but just in case someone else needs it, there is Screen Color Filter app available in iTunes store for macOS. Works similar to iOS Color Filters under Accessibility -> Display Accommodations.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screen-colors-filter-color-tint-dim-hev-block/id1177401419